# Should I flag sub posts for deletion or is it enough with the main post?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm not sure if this question is too subjective, but let me know if there is a more suiting forum for it.

I have three tables: `Products`, `Variations` and `Colors`.

Each table has the field `visibility` and if it's set to `1` the post is visible, if it's set to `0` it's hidden. `Products` is the parent table and it has relations to the child tables `Variations` and `Colors` separately. You can delete posts from any table, but if you delete a post from the `Products` table, any related post from `Variations` or `Colors` are also considered deleted, no matter if their `visibility` field is set to `1` or `0`.

If a product is deleted is it best to scan all the tables and mark everything as deleted, or is it enough to just mark the post in the parent table?

I can see the benefit of undeleting a parent post and having the history of the child tables intact, but you can also argue that they are indirectly deleted and should be marked as such, maybe gain some microseconds in query time and finally avoid mistakes if a join or check for the visibility field is missing somewhere in the code. Any other arguments you can think of for the two approaches?

Comment: First decide if you're talking about posts or products and please edit your question to be consistent.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am consistent. `Products` is the parent table. Posts exist in all three tables. Please read again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `visibility` column determines if post is deleted or not I think you can have it only in the parent table `Products` and it is not needed in the child tables `Variations` and `Colors`. If there is a relation between `Products` and the other two tables you can always use `JOIN` and know what is marked as deleted.

For example if you have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Products` p 
LEFT JOIN `Variations` v ON p.product_id = v.product_id
LEFT JOIN `Colors` c ON p.product_id = c.product_id
WHERE p.visibility = 1;
```

you will get the data only for the visible products and if you want to get deleted data from child table you can do something like:

```
SELECT v.* FROM `Variations` v 
LEFT JOIN `Products` p ON v.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.visibility = 0;
```

The last query will get you the records from `Variations` that are marked as deleted.

### Conclusion

You can always determine the state of a child by parent field in one-to-many relation when using `JOIN` statements so just update the field in the parent table and I think the same field is redundant in the child tables.